# When to add http(s):// to website address

Tags: http, url, swift, https

I'm trying to create a web browser using Cocoa and Swift. I have an `NSTextField` where the user can enter the website he wants to open and a `WebView` where the page requested is displayed. So far, to improve the user experience, I'm checking if the website entered by the user starts with `http://` and add it if it doesn't. Well, it works for most of the cases but not every time, for example when the user wants to open a local web page or something like `about:blank`. How can I check if adding `http://` is necessary and if I should rather add `https://` instead of `http://`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be more precise in your categorization of what the user typed in.
Here are some examples and expected reactions:

1. www.google.com: should be translated into http://www.google.com
2. ftp://www.foo.com: Should not be modified. Same goes to file:// (local)
3. Barrack Obama: Should probably run a search engine
4. about:settings: Should open an internal page

So after you figure out these rules with all their exceptions, you can use a regex to find out what should be done.

As for HTTP vs. HTTPS - if the site supports HTTPS, you'll get a redirect response (307 Internal Redirect, 301 Moved Permanently etc) if you go to the HTTP link. So for example, if you try to navigate to http://www.facebook.com, you'll receive a 307 that will redirect you to https://www.facebook.com. In other words, it's up to the site to tell the browser that it has HTTPS (unless of course you navigated to HTTPS to begin with).

Answer (score 0):

A simple and fairly accurate approach would simply be to look for the presence of a different schema.  If the string starts with `[SomeText]:` before any slashes are encountered, it is likely intended to indicate a different schema such as `about:`, `mailto:`, `file:` or `ftp:`.

If you do not see a non-http schema, try resolving the URL as an HTTP URL by prepending `http://`.